# How to get absolute URL in angular HTTP Interceptor?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

In our application, with every request, the front end hashes the url + the data and sends them to the server.  The server then verifies that the query parameters as well as the data have not been tampered.  However, in the httpinterceptor, I can only view config.url and config.params.  There is no way to get the absolute url, so I can't hash against it directly.  How would I go about doing this?  I tried something along the lines of

```
var url;
var params;
for (var i = 0; i < config.params.length; i++){
    params+=config.params[i].name+'='+config.params[i].value;
}
url = config.url+'?'+params;
```

However this doesn't work because I can't seem to access the params this way.  Also, how can I be sure that the params are in the same order as the request url?  Obviously if it's even 1 character different, the hash won't be right.

Comment: Why not `window.location.href` ?

Comment: why is it so hard to get absolute url? You know what the base is in your app and could easily set it as a constant

Comment: @charlietfl Getting the base url is fine with config.url, but I need the query string as well.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis, window.location.href only helps with the url of the page I'm on.  It can't help me get the URL of API calls

Comment: i am in exact need of this. i have posted a separate question too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171297/how-read-the-url-and-parameter-from-http-interceptor-httpprovider-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding a filter and push to interceptors

```
angular.module("app").config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
        }
        else {
        }
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    }
]);
```

and write your filter to intercept request and response and its error

```
angular.module('app').factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
      // optional method
      'request': function(config) {

        return config;
      },

      // optional method
     'requestError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },



      // optional method
      'response': function(response) {
        // do something on success
        return response;
      },

      // optional method
     'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });
```

in request the config parameter will have the URL as well as the parameter