# How to design a middleware which attaches token to every URL going to external API provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-core

I'm working on building a web application which communicates with external API's. So basically I'm using React + Dotnet Core, what I need is a middleware which will attach the token to every URL leaving the app to the external API provider so that I don't need to worry about attaching the header to every URL.

From frontend, I'm calling backend controller which consist URLs to API endpoint. I need middleware between backend and API endpoint.

I come from Laravel, Nodejs world and very new to the .net world, this question may sound dumb but I have stuck on this, not sure where to begin, any hints or directions will be helpful.

Edit:

I'm storing the token in `_cache` using the key, the middleware needs to get token from `_cache`

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> getApps()
            {
                var ul = Path.Combine(_baseurl_SB, "apps");
                return Ok(await ul.WithOAuthBearerToken((String)_cache.Get("sb")).GetJsonAsync());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question correctly, What you looking is need to alter the API (URL) which getting initiated from Client *.js ( React / angular ) need to add something to the URL before it pass through the network.

**1.  Interceptor** -You can use the URL interceptor you can make use of the HTTP interceptor

[angular HTTP interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171297/how-read-the-url-and-parameter-from-http-interceptor-httpprovider-in-angular-js)

**2. Service worker** - Fetch event listener - which will intercept all the GET call initiated from the browser against the registers service worker domain. Service worker can read from the cache ( Cache API or IndexedDb )

Comment: is it possible for you to show an example or any link which do that?

Comment: Updated the answer with link

Answer (score 0):

If passing the token as a request header instead is an option, then this sounds a lot like you could use [Named HttpClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#named-clients) in your Backend and configure request headers there.

In your Startup:

```
services.AddHttpClient("myExternalApiClient", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myExternalApi");
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "myBearerToken from _cache"); // or extract the Bearer token from HttpContext if the token is provided by the frontend. 
});
```

In your Controller (inject IHttpClientFactory)

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.Create("myExternalApiClient");
var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync("myRelativePath");
return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```